# Problema na função supre

Tags: c, string, while

Estou aqui com um problema nesta função **int supre    (char s1[ ], char s2[  ])** , **que calcula o tamanho do maior sufixo de s1 que é prefixo de s2.** Por exemplo se tiver supre ("batota" , "totalidade") deve retornar **4**, uma vez que a string "tota" é sufixo de "batota" que é prefixo de "totalidade".

Tentei fazer esta função com o auxilio da função **strrev ( )** para comparar carater a carater , mas não deu grande sucesso ..

Se houver alguma função que me ajude , qual devo usar? E é possivel fazer sem ajuda de funções auxiliares?

Comment: Coloque o que você já fez para a gente ter uma ideia do que está tentando fazer. Mesmo que tenha problemas e esteja incompleto.

Comment: eu fazia uma solução tipo recursiva que vai testando substrings de `s1` cada vez mais pequenas: eg ... 1) `"batota"` não é sufixo de `"totalidade"` 2) `"atota"` não é sufixo de `"totalidade"` 3) `"tota"` é sufixo de `"totalidade"`

Comment: @OP, você deseja uma maneira para resolver o problema ou quer dicas para resovê-lo?

Answer (score 2):

Esse é um porbleminha que embora simples, não tem mágica pra resolver:
é um algoritmo simples, que a gente consegue pensar e entender como resolver "manualmente" - e o caminho é entender o algoritmo, e depois transcrever para C.

Você tem um conjunto de ferramentas que são as funções par amanipulação de string da biblioteca padrão do C,e  a verificação direta dos caractéres.  Você também pode escrever suas funções se não houver alguma.

Mas então - perceba que é um algoritmo em "etapas" - não é uma coisa de 3 ou 4 linhas - por que você vai ter que no mínimo achar o ponto inícial de busca, e comparar os caracteres a partir dali.

Então, o pseudo-algoritmo em portugues, poderia começar assim:

- prepare uma string vazia de resposta S3.
- achar se há,e a posição N do primeiro caractere de S2 dentro de S1;
- Se não houver N, retorne dizendo que o sufixo é a string vazia
- crie um contador i = 0;
- checkpoint
- copie o caractere S1[N] para a string de resposta S3
- Incremente o valor de i
- se o caractere em S1[N+i] é o final da string (caractere '\x00') - a resposta é o que temos em S3: acresente um mcarcador de final de string em S3 e  retorne S3 (faça o mesmo se chegou ao final de S2)
- compare o caractere  N + i em S2 com o caractere na posição (0 + i) de S2;
- se são diferentes, zere a string S3, e retorne um sufixo vazio (** mas veja a nota abaixo)
- retorne para "checkpoint"

Poronto -agora você traduz isso para "C" - e perceba que na descriçao em portugues surge naturalmente o que será um laço "for" ou "while' em linguagem de programação.

** - ha uma pegadinha nesse algoritmo aí - se a primeira letra da segunda palavra ocorrer mais de uma vez na primeira palavra, a descrição acima não dá conta.  (por exemplo: "batota",  e "tarifa" - 
ele vai achar o primerio "t" de "batota", mas vai parar a busca no "o" - quando o sufixo está após o segundo "t") - ou você repete a busca por "t", ou- pra começar tudo, procura pela primeira letra de S2 em S1, mas da direita para a esquerda -  essa segunda alternativa é muito mais fácil, mas acho que você não terá uma função pronta na stdlib de C para isso - então vai fazer sua própria funçãozinha pra isso (acredite, vale a pena):

- procure pela letra X em S1 a partir do final:
- faça i igual o comprimento total de S1
- heckpoint`verifique se o caractere S1[i] é X - se sim, retorne i
- decremente i
- se i for menor que zero, retorn i (e aproveite o
  retorno de -1 como indicação de que a letra não existem em S1)
- vá para checkpoint

--Pronto agora você já tem onde começar. Não é o propóstio do S.O. dar respostas prontas - então tente traduzir isso para C.